# symfony flex composer InvalidArgumentException

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-flex

So I downloaded symfony 4 with help of this command

```
 composer create-project symfony/skeleton my-project
```

Afterwards, from the project's directory I try to pull the symfony's flex profiler package using command

```
composer require profiler --dev
```

but composer is having issue. Like it wants to pull the package down the standard way and not by utilizing symfony flex

[image]

UPDATE: Issued at https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/306

Comment: Interesting.  I just tried it and got the same error.  Must be something wrong with the alias.  composer require symfony/profiler-pack  --dev will work

Comment: yeah, looks like all aliases got corrupted. Where is the place to issue this? symfony/flex?

Comment: Seems reasonable.  I poked around a bit but I can't find where the aliases are defined or where the flex composer plugin ends up.  Might be a problem on the github recipe site.  So yep, open an issue and see what happens.

Comment: it's been already issued(https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/306) and the  aliases and all flex reciepies are listed under https://symfony.sh

Answer (score 0):

see the answer of [nicolas-grekas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/322029/nicolas-grekas) in the following [link](https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/306)

you can continue using the symfony containers in [this link](https://symfony.sh/), just look for the alias that flex used.

in your case twig for flex is "symfony / twig-bundle", run `composer req symfony / twig-bundle`.

salu2